# Transform function {a,b} ->{x,y} ; how to?

Tags: functions, fitting, neural-networks, machine-learning

I have a 2D list of values that I want to transform/calibrate to another 2D list. I thought of using a `predict` function but I couldn’t get it to output 2 values.

——more——

I have a list of 2D coordinates `{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}`, etc.. and need to find a method/function/model to turn them into `{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}`...

For instance: `{101, 50}, {210, 55}, {305, 47}` translates into `{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}`.

Once the function is calibrated to the control set i will apply it to another set of points to use the same transformation

Comment: Not enough information, by a long shot. Show the list you have, show the kind of transformation you would like to apply, etc etc.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: could you please provide access to the entire dataset via pastebin.com or such, because as presented you would probably want to use 2 Predict calls to generate 2 PredictorFunction, one for xi->ai and one for yi->bi

Answer (score 1):

You could use a neural network. The architecture needed will depend on the specifics of the data and the domain. In this simple example a single `LinearLayer` is used.

```
in = {{101, 50}, {210, 55}, {305, 47}};
out = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}};
trainingData = Thread[in -> out];

nn = NetInitialize@NetChain[{LinearLayer[]}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> 2]
net = NetTrain[nn, trainingData]

net[{300, 50}]
(* {1.91802, 1.01347} *)
```

Comment: Hi Rohit... thanks for that... could you help me add a BasicRecurrentLayer to that? Cuz I’m trying to get my head around it and failing miserably.

Comment: @CuriousDudeFromEgypt You are welcome. Why does mapping the coordinate pairs need a BasicRecurrentLayer? Probably best if you created a new post with more details about the data, what you are trying to accomplish and any code you have tried.

Comment: Hi Rohit, it probably doesn’t... but I thought I do it as well just to learn how to use the `BasicRecurrentLayer` because I cannot get my head around its input/output matrix requirements....

Comment: @CuriousDudeFromEgypt Ah, in that case take a look at the Application section in the docs for [BasicRecurrentLayer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BasicRecurrentLayer.html). There is also [this](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=453&v=2549) great video on RNN's.